# Get value of a sibling element

Tags: javascript

I have the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/q74k8cke/

The code is this:

```
<div>
  <input type="number" value="1"/>
  <button onclick="alert(this.parentElement.childNodes[0].value)">Click me</button>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is I always get undefined, why? I tried `innerHTML`, `text`, `value` and all give me the same result. If I try to do `nodeName` I get `#text` as the output. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

I have to use pure javascript and inline to solve this problem. Adding an ID is not an option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The problem I am having is I always get undefined, why?

Because the first child node of the parent is a `Text` node with whitespace in it, not the `input`. `childNodes` includes all kinds of nodes, not just `Element`s.

You could use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children), which is just children that are `Element`s, but what you're really looking for is [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling), which is exactly what it sounds like: The immediately-previous sibling that's an `Element` (as opposed to a `Text` node, `Comment` node, etc.):

```
<button onclick="alert(this.previousElementSibling.value)">Click me</button>
```

Live example:

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" value="1"/>
  <button onclick="alert(this.previousElementSibling.value)">Click me</button>
</div>
```